# Online Geo Api для российских городов

Tags: геолокация, json, javascript, geo-api

Пожалуйста, подскажите бесплатный online ресурс, где можно получить коды городов в формате JSON по IP адресу. Сейчас использую http://freegeoip.net, но по многим IP возвращает ошибку (не распознает).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [ipgeobase.ru](http://ipgeobase.ru/) и [ipinfodb.com](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php).